# Google Sheets - Using an IF statement in a Query

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making a spreadsheet for taxes on my crypto purchases and sales. I have the QUERY function to pull the data from my main sheet to my TAX sheet but I need my amount of coins to show up negative on a sale. I want to make a number negative if "sell" is present or keep it positive if "buy". I am trying to use an IF statement inside a QUERY.

=QUERY(Trading!$A$3:H1001, "select A,B,C,D,E,G,H where B contains 'Crypto.com'" & if(Trading!F:F = "SELL", Trading!D:D*-1, Trading!D:D*1))

[Link to Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHfkA31N22NFdTMu5RKuSx9hjH-h94s9dpvN6LVCRFI/edit?usp=sharing)

The locked pages are editable but are just used to gather or receive data from the Trading page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only basically guess without access to see your actual sheets, data and layout (screenshots don't help much). That said, conceptually, this should work:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER({Trading!A3:C,UPPER(Trading!D3:D)*-1,Trading!E3:E,Trading!G3:H}, UPPER(Trading!F3:F)="SELL", ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Crypto",Trading!B3:B)))))`

If that does not work, I recommend sharing a link to a sample document, being sure to set the link's Share permissions (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a coder, and it's my first time asking a question like this. I tried to use it but had an error. I edited my post to include a link to the sample sheet. same formulae just dummy data.

Comment: Viewing your sheet was helpful. Try the formula again now.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great to pull the whole thing, but how do I get it to pull only the data when "crypto" and "sell"?

Comment: See the new formula (though currently, you don't have any "Crypto" and "Sell."